# MEF plugin dependency not loading as plugins directory is not checked

Tags: c#, .net, mef, .net-assembly

I'm having problems with MEF not picking up dependencies for loaded components. We have a directory structure that looks like:

C:/MSMQ/DistributionService/[Main application]

C:/MSMQ/Providers/[plugin components]

Of course, we are using a DirectoryCatalog, the plugin is picked up, but one of its' dependencies is not. The error message is:

```
2012-11-02 10:46:59,379 [1] FATAL - Assemblies required by Provider are not found
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'BusinessObjects, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'BusinessObjects, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = <redacted>
LOG: DisplayName = BusinessObjects, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public
KeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/MSMQ/DistributionService/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : DistributedServicePropertyComponents, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\MSMQ\DistributionService\Distr
ibutionService.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partia
l, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

2012-11-02 10:46:59,401 [1] FATAL - Assemblies required by Provider are not found
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'BusinessObjects, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'BusinessObjects, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = B2B\addisona
LOG: DisplayName = BusinessObjects, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public
KeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/MSMQ/DistributionService/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : DistributedServicePropertyComponents, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\MSMQ\DistributionService\DistributionService.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

I believe this is similar to a question on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MEFramework/thread/b34ef4f4-e1f1-4f06-bd42-d7b3d5060f6f/ - but I don't understand the answer.

Is there any way to provide a path to pick the problem assembly up from, or any other suggested solution?

We have only started having this problem recently, but I can't see any changes I'd expect to cause that in our source control history.

Comment: Are you trying to load the assembly from signed (or delay signed) code?

Comment: as far as I am aware, signed code is not involved (except in the framework libraries).

Comment: Then are you trying to load a 64bit assembly from 32bit code?

Comment: Hi penguat - did you get a resolution to this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @PatrickHastings we bunged everything into one folder. It's not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

One or more of your plugins are dependent on the `BusinessObjects` assembly, while your host application does not reference this assembly. You can do either of the following to fix this:

1. Add a reference to this assembly from your main application, so that the plugins can use it when they are loaded.
2. Add this assembly to your **C:\MSMQ\Providers** directory, so that when the plugins are loaded and look for that assembly, they can find it and load it as well.

Comment: This assembly is in the C:\MSMQ\Providers directory, and not being found.